# Twig: how to override id attribute of form_widget?

Tags: symfony, twig

So this is a pretty straightforward question but the solution seems not so straightforward to a twig beginner like myself. Basically, I want to apply some javascript to a set of forms, so I need the field id's to remain the same across those different forms (or to somehow inject these id's into the javascript file which I'm not sure how to do if it is external).

I use this to render the textarea widget:

```
{{ form_widget(form.text) }}
```

Which automatically gives it an id that I want to change. Doing this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.text, {'attr': {'id': 'ootn_blogbundle_entry_text') }}
```

just adds another id to the field and since there are now two of them, the second one (mine) is simply ignored.

How do I tell form_widget to give the textarea a different id?

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate, sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this `{{ form_widget(form.title, { 'id': 'my_custom_id' }) }}`